# Suppress mvc built in jquery client validation attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I have a model which looks like this:

```
public class TimeAdjustData
{
    [IntegerAllowPlus]
    public int? AddStart { get; set; }
    [IntegerAllowPlus]
    public int? AddEnd { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? GivenStart { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? GivenEnd { get; set; }
}
```

My goal here is to allow the user to type in an integer where they can add a plus for positive values. For example they should be able to fill in 20, -20 or +20. Where 20 and +20 will logical be the same.

I created a custom validation attribute and on the client I added a custom client validation rule.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("integerplus", function (value, element, param) {
    if (value[0] === '+') { value = value.substr(1, value.length - 1); }
    return isInteger(value);
});
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("integerplus");
```

isInteger is a function of my own which validates an integer of course.

My problem here is that even if MVC renders correctly an attribute of `data-val-integerplus` it also renders an attribute of `data-val-number`.

[image]

I guess this is because the data type of AddStart and AddEnd is nullable integers. But this causes the effect that even if the input value passes my custom validation it does not pass the built in number client validation.
So somehow I need to avoid the creation of the attribute `data-val-number`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **ModelValidatorProviders.Providers**
You can use it in the global.asax to remove all validator providers with

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
```

this should resolve your problem, but you should look at it because this remove all implicit validators..

**Edit**:

If you don't want to remove the validation for the whole application, just remove it on the page concerned with javascript :

```
$('#yourField').rules('remove', 'number');
```

Comment: I would like the implicit validators to work as normal not just in this case. So turning it off for the whole application does not seems like a good solution sorry.